# Source Files missing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

i am using chrome dev tools for debugging javascript code. Few of my source code seems missing in the source tab of dev tools. I am getting the following error

Request URL - http://localhost:9001/modules/common/partials/modals/medicalprofile/modal.medicalprofile.directive.js
404 not found. 
But i actually have the above path set in my project code

What is the issue here?

thanks

Comment: Could you share your project code?

Comment: Open that URL in your browser. Does it still 404? If so, it's not a devtools issue.